# Symfony2, Trailing slash

Tags: symfony, slash, trailing

i'm facing an issue i don't really know how to solve. I have this route:

```
www.mysite.com/news/{news}
```

On my local machine, i don't have a problem accessing it, but on the live-server a trailing slash gets added, and ofc the route doesn't exist = error.

Why does this slash get added? How to prevent it? Other routes work fine, no "/" added there. This ONLY happens in **app.php** ...**app_dev.php** works fine.

I've tried to remove the trailing slash via mod_rewrite, but then another route doesn't work. ( The FOSUserBundle /register  one ....).

Does anyone know, why there's a trailing slash on the live-server, but not on my local machine? Same **.htacces** and **000-default.conf**. And as stated above **app_dev.php** works fine as well.

Regards

Comment: Can you show us the routing file?

Comment: is the problem connected with urls like 

www.mysite.com/news **/1/**  or www.mysite.com/news **/**   ??

Comment: mod_rewrite module is the problem ...i disabled it now .... and everything works as it should. But i think i need it to remove the "app.php" part from the url ...

Comment: seems like the problem is the .htaccess inside the web folder. I've managed to reproduce the error on my localhost. It's def. the rewrite rule ... but WHY is it adding a slash only to this route?!